# PHP - substr() only if certain character exists?

Tags: php

I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 to grab video titles and IDs to embed videos on a website. I'm just currently having a problem displaying the title in the way that I want it. Some of the video titles have text in brackets at the end, which I don't want to display on the website. I am currently using:

```
$videoTitle = substr($videoTitle, 0, strpos($videoTitle, '('));
```

The problem is that the titles that don't include brackets aren't being displayed. I'm not that experienced with PHP so I'm not sure of a way around this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks,
Oli.

Comment: you also need to add what `$videoTitle` contains, put it also inside the question

Comment: @Perceptic Why don't you wrap into an if query, that tests if a baces does exists in video title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check whether or not the string contains the character, then modify it if it does. Otherwise leave it alone.

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/substr) to check for the existence of the character, since it returns `false` if it does not exist in the string.

```
$videoTitle = strpos($videoTitle, '(') === false ? $videoTitle : substr($videoTitle, 0, strpos($videoTitle, '('));
```

or

```
if (strpos($videoTitle, '(') !== false)
    $videoTitle : substr($videoTitle, 0, strpos($videoTitle, '('))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks. I'll accept the answer when it will let me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just split the string at the `(`, you can only use the first part as video title, like:

```
$splitString = explode('(', $videoTitle);
$videoTitle = $splitString[0];
```

But video titles can look different all the time and you can't really rely on a safe method to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like below.If you will share a link that will be more helpfull.

```
<?php
    $urlarray = explode("(",$videoTitle);
    $videoTitle = $urlarray[0];
?>
```